# rxjava zip not working on specified schedulers?

Tags: java, observable, jax-rs, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have this implementation where I have 2 singles, they are parallel calls to database to fetch objects. Then I use rxjava zip operator to aggregate the result. Like below:

```
...
(other code)

Single<A> a = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Inside single a, running in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io);

Single<B> b = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Inside single b, running in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io);

Single<C> result = Single.zip(a, b, aggregationFunc2())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe(response::resume, response::resume);
```

```
private Func2<a, b, c> aggregationFunc2() {
        System.out.println("Inside aggregationFunc2, running in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return (a, b) -> {
            CBuilder cBuilder = new Builder();
            if (a != null) {
                cBuilder.setA(a);
            }
            if (b != null) {
                cBuilder.setB(b);
            }           
            return cBuilder.build();
        };
    }
```

However, logging I'm getting is that a and b are running both in IO thread pool with different io thread, say io-2 and io-3. That was expected since I specified each single to be in IO scheduler. But zip function is still running in default main thread while I expect it to be in computation thread. Not sure why so, any idea?

Also, I tried observeOn() for zip, it's still running in the default main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you call `aggregationFunc2` on the main thread.

Rewriting your code a bit should reveal the misunderstanding:

```java
Func2<A, B, C> f = aggregationFunc2();
Single<C> result = Single.zip(a, b, f);
```

You print before creating and returning the function itself. You'd have to move the print statement inside the created function:

```java
private Func2<a, b, c> aggregationFunc2() {
    return (a, b) -> {
        System.out.println("Inside aggregationFunc2, running in thread " 
             + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        CBuilder cBuilder = new Builder();
        if (a != null) {
            cBuilder.setA(a);
        }
        if (b != null) {
            cBuilder.setB(b);
        }           
        return cBuilder.build();
    };
}
```